# Add an 'each' like method to a Ruby class that inherits from Hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I'd like to make a class that behaves like a standard Ruby Hash with some extra access methods thrown in. For example, given:

```
class SpecificHash < Hash
  def initialize 
    (1..20).each do |num|
      self[num] = "value #{num.to_s}"
    end
  end
end
```

I can get a full listing of all key value pairs with the standard `each` call:

```
sh = SpecificHash.new
sh.each { |k,v| puts k }
```

I've got several things I'd like to do. To use a simplified example, how would I create a definition for an `odd_keys` method lets me call:

```
sh = SpecificHash.new
sh.odd_keys { |k,v| puts k }
```

and have it work like the `each` method but only contain key/value pairs where the key is an odd number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this method to your class should work:

```
def odd
  return enum_for(:odd) unless block_given?
  each do |k, v|
    if k.respond_to?(:odd?) && k.odd?
      yield k, v
    end
  end
end
```

The first line is pretty standard practice that allows you to return an enumerator if a block is not passed to your method, just like `each` does.  It enables things like:

```
hash.odd.select { ... }
```

Comment: Yes, this was a way better answer!

Comment: I realized that "odd?" is a method to check if integers are odd. I've updated the question to rename the example method to "odd_keys" to distinguish between the two. Is it correct that the only things that need to change are `def odd` to `def odd_keys` and `return enum_for(:odd) unless block_given?` to `return enum_for(:odd_keys) unless block_given?` and `hash.odd.select { ... }` to `hash.odd_keys.select { ... }`?

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like you correctly identified the three places where the method name appears in my answer and you would need to change all of those.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this:

```
class SpecificHash < Hash
  def odd
    each do |k, v|
      yield(k, v) if k.odd?
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the purpose of defining a class for your use case. A single enumerator instance seems to suffice for your purpose.

```
sh = (1..20).lazy
sh.map{|k| [k, "value #{k}"]}.to_h # => ...
sh.each{|k| puts k} # => ...
sh.select(&:odd?).each{|k| puts k} # => ...
```

Comment: I should have been more clear that the specific use case is just an example. What I'm really looking for is the technique of generating "each" type output from a hash based on filtering. For example, a Hash containing a list of people indexed by ID where I want to make method calls to return different sub sets based on properties of each person. I was trying to simplify the example, but may have taken it a little too far.

Comment: Still, it is better to use a lazy enumerator. You can make a lazy enumerator out of a hash or an array. It lets you add a chain of methods to create a "subset" without creating intermediate arrays/hashes, and so, it is efficient.